# Printing a matrix

Tags: c, algorithm, multidimensional-array

The problem is: Given the height (h) and width (w) of a canvas (in other words, a 2D array) on the first line; and the co-ordinates of the centre (x, y) and the radius (r) of a circle, print the canvas. If an element of the 2D array is within the circle, print `#` else print `.`. Below is what I have tried, but for the life of me I can't figure out why the 2D matrix only contains `.`s. Please throw some light:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct point {
    int x;
    int y;
} point;

float distance(point p, point q) {
    return sqrt((p.x - q.x)*(p.x - q.x) + (p.y - q.y)*(p.y - q.y));
}

int withinCircle(point circleCentre, point p, int radius) {
    float dist = distance(circleCentre, p);
    if (!(dist > (float) radius)) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main(void){
    point pixel;
    int w, h;
    scanf("%d %d",&w,&h);
    char *canvas = malloc(w * h);

    int circleX, circleY; 
    int r; 
    scanf("%d %d %d",&circleX,&circleY,&r);
    point circleCentre;
    circleCentre.x = circleX; circleCentre.y = circleY;

    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {
            pixel.x = j; pixel.y = i;
            if (withinCircle(circleCentre, pixel, r)) {
                *(canvas + i + j) = '#';
            } else {
                *(canvas + i + j) = '.';
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {
              printf("%c", *(canvas + i + j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output (20 and 16 are the width (w) and height (h) respectively. 9, 6 and 5 are the circle's X co-ordinate (x), Y co-ordinate (y) and radius (r) respectively):

```
20 16
9 6 5
....................
....................
....................
....................
....................
....................
....................
....................
....................
....................
....................
....................
....................
....................
....................
....................
```

Comment: where do you print w,h,x,y and r in your code? Or is this just an assumption that these values are really in there? Because you make it look like a print.

Comment: `*(canvas + i + j)` ----> `*(canvas + j + (i*w))` ....`i` must be multiple of row width

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for this is here: `*(canvas + i + j)`.

Suppose `i == 1` and `j == 1` (second row, second element). In your contiguous array this as at position `1*w + 1` but `*(canvas + i + j)` gives you the position `1 + 1`.

So `i` should be multiplied by `w` to 'skip' `i` rows (each of length `w`):

`*(canvas + i*w + j)`

You can see a fixed live demo on [ideone](http://ideone.com/CuJGwE)

Comment: just wanted to write this. beat me to it.

Comment: Me too. I commented the same. ;) +1